# Masonry broken (probably a classic)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, masonry

I thought it is a pretty straight-forward setup, but somehow I am missing something...

This is the outgoing HTML. It's a simple fixed-width 2-column layout:

```
<div class="container_12">
   <div class="grid_masonry"> ... </div>
   <div class="grid_masonry"> ... </div>
   <div class="grid_masonry"> ... </div>
   ...
</div>
```

The masonry JS is linked in the `<head>` (also jQuery, just to be save):

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

Te scripts a loading normally.

This is how the effect is called to action:

```
<div class="container_12" data-masonry='{ "itemSelector": ".grid_masonry" }'>
```

I tried to call it through jQuery (code below) but it did nothing, not even a broken effect.

```
$('.container_12').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.grid_masonry'
});
```

This is the grid element's CSS:

```
.container_12 {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   width: 960px;
}

...

.grid_masonry {
    margin-bottom: 32px;
    float: left;
    width: 380px;
}

.grid_masonry:nth-child(odd) {
    /* gutter */
    margin-right: 160px;
}
```

I was hoping one might recognise the damage and know what the problem could be...

Comment: can you post up a jsfiddle or code snippet?

Comment: @MrRioku https://jsfiddle.net/7q230kk2/

Comment: Update: It sort of works with the HTML class to call up masonry, but that way it can't preload the images. So I have to use Jquery, but it doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/Lqf1pqgx/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

Check these things if you run into my problems yourself:

- Do you have all the libraries properly loaded?
  jQuery 2, imagesLoaded 4, Masonry 4
- Is the width of the container and the widths of the elements inside allowing the elements to float side by side? Gutters can be made in CSS with `margin-right` and `margin-left` being applied to `.element:nth-child(odd) {}` and `.element:nth-child(even) {}` for a two-column layout. When there is more, the inside columns have both margins applied.
- Always use the jQuery alternative rather than the HTML class way. It's better to customise.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the .grid-sizer which tells masonry what the unit is to follow for the masonry container. Search for "grid-sizer" here: http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html

Comment: But the width is already specified with the defined width of the grid elements. I understood from that website that I would need that only if I have different widths and percentage width. But I have one fixed pixel width. Only the heights are variable.

Comment: It looks from the documentation that even a fixed width still needs grid-sizer to have that declared and be included in your html and called in the jquery initialisation. Then  you can use a percentage unit or static width for the grid-sizer unit.

Comment: I think, narrowed down, it seems that the problem is that it does not float. And masonry with just one column is 'invisible' masonry.

Comment: At the top of the documentation: "All options are optional, but columnWidth and itemSelector are recommended." So either set the columnWidth with grid-sizer or in the jQuery masonry call to load it: "columnWidth: 200,"

Comment: It's a guest account with no power

Comment: I still haven't found a solution. This should be 100% standard procedure. Why is it that no plugin just works when used in the most banal situation....

Comment: I was able to fix the "one column" effect now. Actually now it works, just the images should load _before_  the masonry. And I can't get the jQuery thing to work. I used the HTML class way, but that doesn't allow image preloading.  This is the JS that doesn't do anything: http://pastebin.com/iqsNgTrj but why?

Comment: You also need to run ImagesLoaded to delay masonry until the images load. Also make sure masonry loads after  Jquery https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

Comment: Yes, I know. I am trying that, look at the pastebin-link. I can't get it to work. And the <link> for jQuery comes before the <link> for Masonry.

Comment: If you have a URL with the example, not on your WP admin then I could inspect errors. Are you running jquery 1 or 2?

Comment: (again, it was a guest account only to look at, obviously not the admin account) But here is some jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lqf1pqgx/1/

Comment: o.m.g. I got the problem now: `imagesLoaded` is a whole library, not just some command. Would be nice to have that mentioned at the place where they tell you that you can just add `imagesLoaded` that you gonna have to import another library. Now it works. 4 hours just to find out that you have to import a library that is mentioned nowhere.

Comment: Yes they do lot make it very clear at all, glad you got it sorted!